# How do you integrate this inverse product of series

Tags: integration

Ive spent hours thinking of this but Ive got no idea how to solve this.

$$
 \int \frac{dx}{x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+k)}
$$

Do I use partial fraction or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Partial fractions. You can even use the cover-up technique.

Comment: Simply use the method of rational fractions. By the way, it will hold iff $k$ is an small one, else it will look more cumbersome while deciding the values of $A,B\dots$ where we consider the integrand=$\frac A{x+1}+\frac B{x+2}+\dots.$.

Comment: at first compute an example

Comment: I tried partial fractions but i cant seem to find the general term for the coefficient for each term. Take k=5 for example, the coefficients are 1/5!, -1/4!,1/3!,-1/3!,1/4!,-1/5!. I mean clearly a human can see the pattern but i cant express it in mathematical terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Partial fraction Method

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)........(x+k)} = \frac{A_{0}}{x}+\frac{A_{1}}{x+1}+\frac{A_{2}}{x+2}+........+\frac{A_{k}}{x+k} = \sum^{k}_{r=0}\frac{A_{r}}{x+r}$$

For some Suitable $A_{r}\;,$ after Simplifying, We get

$$\displaystyle A_{r} = \frac{1}{\underbrace{-r(-r+1)(-r+2)....(-r+(r-1))}_{\bf{r\; terms \; from \; which \; we \; will\; take \; -1\; as \; a \; factor}}\times (-r+r+1)(-r+r+2)......(-r+k)}$$

$$\displaystyle A_{r} = \frac{1}{(-1)^rr(r-1)(r-2)....(r-(r-1))\times 1.2....(k-r)}$$(taking out $r$ factors of $-1$)

$\displaystyle A_{r} = \frac{(-1)^r}{r!\times (k-r)!}$ as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{(-1)^r} = (-1)^{r}$

So $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2).......(x+k)}dx = \int\sum^{k}_{r=0}\frac{A_{r}}{x+r}dx\;,$ Where $\displaystyle A_{r} = \frac{(-1)^r}{r!\times (k-r)!}$

So $$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2).......(x+k)}dx=\sum^{k}_{r=0}\int\frac{A_{r}}{x+r}dx = \sum^{k}_{r=0}A_{r}\ln|x+r|+\mathcal{C}$$

So $$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2).......(x+k)}dx = \sum^{k}_{r=0}\frac{(-1)^r}{r!\times (k-r)!}\ln|x+r|+\mathcal{C}$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, partial fraction decomposition is the way to go. For any $n\in[1,k]$ we have:

$$ \text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{x(x+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x+k)},x=-n\right) = \prod_{\substack{j\in[0,k]\\j\neq n}}\frac{1}{(-n+j)}=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!(k-n)!}$$
and the residue at $x=0$ is obviously $\frac{1}{k!}$, hence:

> $$ \int \frac{dx}{x(x+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x+k)}=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{n=0}^{k}\binom{k}{n}(-1)^n \log(x+n)+C.$$

Comment: Aren't residues a little bit too advanced for someone who asks about partial fractions?

Comment: Awesome answer, I didn't even think of that.

Comment: @JamMaster: to compute residues or the coefficients of a partial fraction decomposition is just the same, so your question sounds like *"Isn't to compute $A$ a little too advanced for someone who's asking to compute $A$?"*

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Well yes its the same thing and I think this is a prettier solution, but I don't think he had residues yet so this answer might just confuse him.

Comment: @JamMaster: in such a case, let we just state the following almost trivial lemma. If $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x(x+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(x+k)}=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{A_j}{x+j},$$ then: $$ A_j = \lim_{x\to -j}(x+j)\cdot f(x) = \text{Res}\left(f(x),x=-j\right).$$